# How to store video in my created directory using download manager in android version 10 or 10+

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, runtime-error, android-10.0

I have write `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest  tag.

Also i have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

both permission in manifest file.

Also .java code for download is

```
 public void download(int position)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Downloading start..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(videoItems.get(position).VideoUrl));
        request.setDescription("Downloading..");
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setTitle(videoItems.get(position).VideoName);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/bgm bingo" ,videoItems.get(position).VideoName+".mp4");
        manager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        id = manager.enqueue(request);
        mContext.registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
```

Still i not able to store my video in my created app folder.

This code perfect run android version 9 or less but when android version is 10 or 10+ then this code will not work. so how to solve it. please give me solution.

Comment: You did not tell full path of your created app folder.

Comment: So how to give full path please tell me.

Comment: How did you create your app folder if you were not aware where you did that?